# Futures returning data inconsistently

Tags: java, parallel-processing, database-connection, future

I am not an expert in futures in Java but I am trying to make database calls in parallel using the callable tasks.
so every callable task i create basically executes the whole query for a subset of the parameters 
For simplicity assume it is something like

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEES IN (A,B,C,D)`

EDITED:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOME CASE // whole query takes lot of time
```

ASSUME  WE HAVE lot of data for these parameters and 
instead I am having callable tasks for

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEES IN (A)
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEES IN (B)
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEES IN (C)
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEES IN (D)
```

EDIT

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SUBSET 1 OF PARAMETERS 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SUBSET 2 OF PARAMETERS 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SUBSET 3 OF PARAMETERS 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SUBSET 4 OF PARAMETERS
```

Using futures this is what i am trying to do

```
List<Future<T>> resultFutures ; //T is just a ResultSet parsed into a List of POJO.
SomeList //list of A,B,C,D as shown above
        .parallelStream()
        . forEach(chunk -> {
            tasks.add(new Task<>(       
                    chunk
                    ));
        });
resultFutures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
```

Think of every task executing a new jdbc connection to a database and returning the result.
I am doing this to get the results of the futures

```
resultFutures 
.parallelStream()
                    .map(future -> {
                        try {
                            return future.get();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMap(f -> f.parallelStream())      
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works correctly but the results are unpredictable and sometimes I get less rows while at times I get the correct result.
No exception is thrown in cases when the result rows are lesser than expected.
can you guys help out by telling if this is the correct way to use futures?
my database is SQL server and I am using jdbc connection via spring.

Comment: There's no sense in dividing the query like that though. It's a lot more efficient to do it as a single query.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot post the original query due to code sharing concerns at my company, but assume that the whole query takes a lot of time to execute.
I am not splitting the query as shown above and neither is the query structure like that. It is simply to provide more context as to what I am trying to do.
The question that needs to be addressed is why I could possibly get lesser data in some cases and correct in the other cases.

Comment: You seem to be using `parallelStream()` everywhere. Why? Is your `tasks` a thread-safe collection?

Comment: yes, every query returns part of the data and no shared objects are being used.
Its basically a reporting tool where where you can query for certain parameters and query for more parameters. the data is discrete and the result should be the same. so if you query for A-Z at once or split it like [A-C) , [C,E)... [X-Z] it should still give same result as [A-Z]

Comment: I asked if your `tasks` is a thread-safe collection. You're using parallel streams to insert the tasks in the collection.

Comment: Oh I was conceptually unclear as to thread safety. No its is not thread safe! 
I work around that and come up with a solution! Thanks @Kayaman

Comment: Is it really necessary to use parallel streams? Do you really think you're getting a useful performance advantage from it?